# Error with setting the value of excel worksheet

Tags: c#, excel, visual-studio, epplus, solidworks

Without going into too much detail, this is my first project. I am very new at coding and this may be a very simple oversight on my part. I am an engineer and I need to add some "custom properties" to over 1000+ CAD files. I am using excel to assign set properties to each file.

I am using `EPPlus`.

I have a `using OfficeOpenXml;` statement.

During debugging, I get an error at line 73: `worksheet.Cells[row, 6].Value = file;`

> System.NullReferenceException: 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.worksheet was null."

I can see that the value for "var worksheet" at line 64 is null but I can't figure out why...

---

```
public static void InsertPropName2()
{
    string ExFile = @"J:\VB Test\Excel\SW.Prop.xlsx";
    var FileInfo = new FileInfo(ExFile);

    List<string> DrwPropName = new List<string>()
    {
        "MPN",
        "Description",
        "OEM Location",
        "Material",
        "Surface Finish",
        "Hardness",
        "Color",
    };

    List<string> PartPropName = new List<string>()
    {
        "MPN",
        "Description",
        "Drawn",
        "Q.A. Approved",
        "Checked",
        "Engineering Approved",
        "Revision",
        "Drawn By:",
        "Drawn Date",
        "Q.A. Approval",
        "Q.A. App. Date",
        "Checked By",
        "Checked Date",
        "Engineering Approval",
        "Engineering App. Date",
    };

    List<int> PartPropType = new List<int>()
    {
        30,
        30,
        30,
        30,
        30,
        30,
        30,
        30,
        64,
        30,
        64,
        30,
        64,
        30,
        64,
    };

    using (ExcelPackage excel = new ExcelPackage(FileInfo))
    {
        string directory = @"J:\Move (Test)\a";
        string[] Files = Directory.GetFiles(directory);

        foreach (string file in Files)
        {
           string WSName = file.Substring(file.Length - 31);

            //line 64
            var worksheet = excel.Workbook.Worksheets[WSName];

            string FileType = file.Substring(file.Length - 6);

            switch (FileType)
            {
                case "SLDDRW":
                    int row = 1;
                    int a = 0;

                    //line 73
                    worksheet.Cells[row, 6].Value = file;
                    foreach (string prop in DrwPropName)
                    {
                        worksheet.Cells[row, 7].Value = DrwPropName[a];
                        worksheet.Cells[row, 8].Value = 30;
                        a++;
                    }

                    break;

                case "SLDPRT":
                    int row2 = 1;
                    int b = 0;
                    worksheet.Cells[row2, 6].Value = file;
                    foreach (string prop in PartPropName)
                    {
                        worksheet.Cells[row2, 7].Value = PartPropName[b];
                        worksheet.Cells[row2, 8].Value = PartPropType[b];
                        b++;
                        row2++;
                    }

                    break;

                case "SLDASM":
                    int row3 = 1;
                    int c = 0;
                    worksheet.Cells[row3, 6].Value = file;
                    foreach (string prop in PartPropName)
                    {
                        worksheet.Cells[row3, 7].Value = PartPropName[c];
                        worksheet.Cells[row3, 8].Value = PartPropType[c];
                        c++;
                        row3++;
                    }

                    break;

                default:

                    break;
            }
        }
        excel.Save();
    }
}
```

Any help is greatly appreciated. Again sorry if this is a very simple noob error!

edit:
I have another class that I run before I run this that creates an excel file with the worksheets in question above so I know the worksheet exists. I have also visual checked to see if that the excel file has the worksheets in question. the code in the other class executes and I have no errors with that part of my project.

The `WSName` is not declared anywhere else in the class so It is not the same as other NullReferenceException threads.

Part of the code that's in the other class:

```
using (ExcelPackage excel = new ExcelPackage(FileInfo))
{
    string WSName = file.Substring(file.Length - 31);

    var worksheet = excel.Workbook.Worksheets.Add(WSName);
```

Comment: What line is 64? And 73?

Comment: Looks like there no worksheet with name `WSName` available in the workbook. Did you write this code to create new excel file and create new worksheet in it and write data to it?

Comment: during debugging when I check for the value at line 64 var worksheet is null

Comment: WSName is coded the same in both classes in this project it is the name of the CAD file.

Comment: When you debug through the code, please check the value of `WSName` in your `Immediate Window` using `?WSName`. What value is shown there?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a NullReferenceException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for trying to solve the issue. I figured out what the problem was.

`WSName` was set from code  `Directory.GetFiles(directory);` so I can keep track of the properties to each CAD file.

When the first class member used the value of `WSName` to create the worksheet. The value for `WSName` had "\". The actual name of the worksheet omitted the "\" even though I used the "@" symbol in front of the string. It must me a limitation of excel. When the second class member tried to write to the worksheet even though `WSName` was coded the same way as the first member it could not find it due to the missing "\".